# Slick JS Custom Navigation not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a basic slickJS 1.8 Carousel and trying to modify how pagination looks. There are many stackoverflow similar questions however none worked for me. Carousel works, I can swipe on left and right, dots work fine however I'd like to achieve this presentation when it comes to navigation <- 1/3 -> (where -> or <- is an icon) Here is the setup

```
var $status = $('.count');
var $slickElement = $('.carousel');

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
        var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
        $status.html('<button type="button" class="custom-prev"><</button>' + '<span class="current_slide">' + i + '</span> / <span class="total_slides"> ' + slick.slideCount + '</span>' + '<button type="button" class="custom-next">></button>');
    });



    $('.carousel').slick({
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 4.5,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        arrows: true,
        nextArrow: $('.custom-next'),
        prevArrow: $('.custom-prev'),


        responsive: [
            {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3,
                infinite: true,
                dots: true
            }
            },
            {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2
            }
            },
            {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            }
            }
            // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
            // settings: "unslick"
            // instead of a settings object
        ]
    });
```

Next and Previous buttons appear however navigation to next slides don't work but dots work. Disabled dots for didn't make any difference to my custom next and previous buttons, is there anything I'm doing wrong? I'm not a JS expert hence some guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this with a few amends here but you will still need to tweak it to get the presentation you want. See comments in code for explanation.

Example: https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/56c63447c77c07e84407f08016cf17b2

```
var $status = $('.count');
var $slickElement = $('.slick-slider');

// You only need to add the controls on init. Anything more will probably result in issues with behaviour.
$slickElement.on('init', function () {
  $status.before('<button type="button" class="custom-prev"><</button>' + '<button type="button" class="custom-next">></button>');
});

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  var i = slick.currentSlide + 1; // This will get you the current slide on init.
  $status.html('<span class="current_slide">' + i + '</span> / <span class="total_slides">' + slick.slideCount + '</span>');
});

// I've simplified this for sake of example. You have to bare in mind that if your slidesToShow is more than 1 then your numbered pagination probably wont work how you expect as the number will reflect the first item in a row.
$('.slick-slider').slick({
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  nextArrow: $('.custom-next'),
  prevArrow: $('.custom-prev'),
});

// Not having the arrow controls within the slick container probably results in the event listeners not being added. You can simply add them yourself here.
$('.custom-prev').click(function(){
  $slickElement.slick('slickPrev');
})

$('.custom-next').click(function(){
  $slickElement.slick('slickNext');
})
```